# Pandas plot with errorbar: style does not apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas (version 0.14.1) `DataFrame` object like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
                      [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]),
                  columns=['y', 'dy'])
```

It returns

```
    y   dy
0   1   0.1
1   2   0.3
2   3   0.1
3   4   0.2
4   5   0.4
```

where the first column is *value* and the second is *error*.

**First case**: I want to make a plot for `y`-values

```
df['y'].plot(style="ro-")
```

[image: First case]

**Second case**: I want to add a vertical errorbars `dy` for `y`-values

```
df['y'].plot(style="ro-", yerr=df['dy'])
```

[image: Second case]

So, If I add `yerr` or `xerr` parameter to `plot` method, It ignores `style`.

Is it Pandas feature or bug?

Comment: Bug: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7023 A pull request is welcome.

Comment: @TomAugspurger thanks for the link. I turned your comment into an answer, I hope it is ok. Hate seeing resolved questions in the "unanswered" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [TomAugspurger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889400/tomaugspurger) pointed out, it is a [known issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7023). However, it has an easy workaround in most cases: use `fmt` keyword instead of `style` keyword to specify shortcut style options.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
                      [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]),
                  columns=['y', 'dy'])

df['y'].plot(fmt='ro-', yerr=df['dy'], grid='on')
```

[image: correctly styled figure]